# How to translate "so to speak"?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire

I would like to know how to translate “so to speak” in French. So far, the only thing I can come up with is *disons que*.

Comment: There are on line tools to answer this type of questions. [Reverso](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/so%20to%20speak), [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_to_speak), [Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/so+to+speak.html). French Language and usage isn't a dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"*So to speak*" means "*pour ainsi dire*".

Answer (score 3):

The correct translation is

> Façon de parler

Which would be the literal translation for “way to speak”.

Example:

> *Je suis bien meilleur joueur de tennis que lui, je vais le détruire ! Enfin, façon de parler.*

Comment: +1. Ajoutons la variante [légèrement moins courante](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mani%C3%A8re+de+dire%2C+fa%C3%A7on+de+parler&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=) *manière de dire*.

Comment: Depending on the level of language you have to use `Pour ainsi dire` is a bit more formal, and `Facon de parler` more familiar. I would avoid using the later in an official context.

Answer (score 2):

«c'est à dire» would be the correct way if you think about how to convey the same idea (instead of word to word translation) from English to French.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense too. I don't know why I never thought of that before.